# Add option a select field in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am using AJAX call to fetch data to edit my form

After that I am loading form in jQuery dialog and setting values of field

But I am not able to add options fields of select input type (not able to get list in select menu I am using chosen -jquery for that)

Here is my code

```
function edit(intvalue) {
    aucid = intvalue;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: 'controller/controller_remateedit.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data: {
            remate_id: aucid
        }, // our data object
        dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode: true,

        success: function (data) {
            //what to do in success

            $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                show: 'blind',
                hide: 'blind',
                width: 900,
                dialogClass: 'ui-dialog',


                create: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#base").val(data.remate_data.base);

                    var o = new Option("option text", "value");

                    $(o).html("option text");
                    $("#property").append(o);
                    $("#content").jqteVal(data.remate_data.edicto);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
you need a change

```
    var o = new Option("1", "value");
    $(o).html("option text");
    $("#property").append($(o));
```

see  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epuj0p91/1/)

Comment: yes it is working outside the dialog but I want to add fields when the dialog loads

Comment: do you need to add one option, or an array of options? Are you getting the option text from the ajax call?

Comment: no I am not getting it from ajax call its just a demo text for checking whether field is added or not .. I will replace it with data from ajax call after it appends...I just want to know how to append inside a dialog

Comment: no , nvm I do it another way I will fetch data in php variable in same page and then load elements in form after that I will load my doalog

Thanks for your help :)